# Expectation Maximisation (EM) Algorithm

Tags: expectation-maximization, likelihood

Some of my parameters do not have a closed form solution. Thus, for these parameters the M-step is implemented via a one-step Newton-Raphson update, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\theta^{t+1} = \theta^t - \bigg[\frac{\partial S(\theta^t)}{\partial \theta}\bigg]^{-1}S(\theta^t),
\end{equation}

where $S(\theta^t)$ is the score vector corresponding to $l(\theta^t)$.

One parameter that does not have a closed form has support $(0, +\infty)$. During some proposals of the algorithm

\begin{equation}
 \theta^t < \bigg[\frac{\partial S(\theta^t)}{\partial \theta}\bigg]^{-1}S(\theta^t),
\end{equation}

and so I get a negative value returned for $\theta_t$, which is not possible. Are there any constraints that I can apply to prevent this from happening?

Another issue I have is with the observed log-likelihood:

The log-likelihood has a $\log(1-F(u))$ term, where F is a cdf. It is not unlikely that $F(u) = 1$ for some data points, this means that the log-likelihood returns $-\infty$. What can one do when some iterations of an algorithm have this issue?

Comment: To keep a parameter positive it helps to represent it as a square of another parameter: $\theta = \alpha^2$. Than $\alpha$ can take any values and one can use usual optimization procedures.

Comment: @Vadim Yes, this would likely solve the first problem. I was thinking about using $\theta  = e^{\alpha}$.

Comment: For the second problem you could use $\log (1 +h - F(u))$, where $h$ is a small number, e.g. $h=10^{-8}$. It is crude, but often solves the problem.